# Python Using question marks in print statements?

Tags: python

I am trying to print c if a > b, else I want to print d. Currently I am using if statements, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this using question marks, as it complicates the code too much. I have seen it done before, but couldn't find any documentation on this.

```
#Current code
c = 'xxxxx'
d = 'xxxxxx'
print 'I like pie ',
if a > b:
    print c,
else:
    print d,
print ' that\'s why you should too!'
```

Comment: By question marks, I assume you mean the terniary operator, `a = b ? c : d` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by "question marks" you mean the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator) `a > b ? c : d`.  This syntax is from non-Python languages; in Python, the equivalent syntax for [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) uses English keywords:

```
print (c if a > b else d),
```

(The parentheses aren't strictly necessary here, and you'll need to be careful if you try to run this in Python 3, but it makes the code easier to read.)